# HTTP/SOAP services on Linux - recommendation please

Tags: linux, soap

I'm looking to set up a scalable server farm that serves up HTTP/SOAP requests and read/writes  data from and to a (set of) database(s). Looking for the right Linux tools to handle that. Can someone please recommend a path for me? just a point in the right direction is all I require. In the past I used LAMP for PHP. What should I use jus for HTTP/SOAP? is there some kind of Apache extension for SOAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest two general approaches:

- Using Apache HTTPD and using PHP, Python or Perl, using SSI/CGI/mod_python/WSGI, depending on how you want to set up your application. (A variant of this is to use a standalone Python/Perl server if you don't need the benefits of Apache HTTPD.) PHP, Python and Perl have SOAP server-side libraries (I've found SOAP::Lite in Perl very hard to debug and work with, but there may be other libraries, or you may like it...)
- Using a Java container, perhaps with something like Axis or Metro.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache webserver](http://httpd.apache.org/) with Apache's [Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/) server for web services SOAP should be fine.